Lattice Diamond Verilog timing error in place and route report
I'm trying to write a simple frequency counter in Verilog and what I found is that if I try to copy my 'counter' register I get an error pop-up window saying "There's a timing error in place and route report. Do you want to continue with the flow?" How to mitigate the issue?
module FreqCounter2(
input wire Clk,
input wire Signal,
output wire [7 : 0] Counter,
output wire [2 : 0]SCKout
);

parameter MEASURE_STATE = 0;
parameter COPY_COUNTER_STATE = 1;
parameter RESET_CLK_COUNTER_STATE = 2;

reg [7 : 0] counter = 0;
reg [7 : 0] counterBuffer_reg = 0;
reg [2 : 0] SignalReg = 0;  
reg [2 : 0] state = 0;

assign Counter = counter;
assign SCKout = SignalReg;
assign counterBuffer = counter;

wire SignalRisingEdge = (SignalReg[2:1] == 2'b01); //detect rising edge of the incoming signal

always @(posedge Clk)
begin
    case(state)
    MEASURE_STATE:
    begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
        if(SignalRisingEdge == 1)
        begin
            state <= COPY_COUNTER_STATE;
        end
    end

    COPY_COUNTER_STATE:
    begin
        counterBuffer_reg <= counter; //this line drives me nuts
        //When I try to copy counter I get a message:
        //"There's a timing error in place and route report. Do you want to continue with the flow?"

        state <= RESET_CLK_COUNTER_STATE;
    end

    RESET_CLK_COUNTER_STATE:
    begin
        state <= MEASURE_STATE;
        counter <= 0;
    end
    endcase
end

endmodule



counterBuffer is assigned but not declared (counterBuffer_reg is not counterBuffer).

SignalReg seems to be fixed to 0.

There is no async reset in your logic (It's relatively fine for just FPGA)

You mixed comination logics into sequential logics (check google for state and next_state fsm).


Timing is not meaningful if logics aren't reasonable.
Make RTL reasonable then we can deal with any real timing issue.
